# MVC login page can't find a DLL even though it is already been dynamically loaded

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dll, plugins

I have an MVC login page, and I'm trying to use some .DLLs which I've already created for other purposes.  These .DLLs are really plugins and they are located in a `/CorePlugins` folder in my webpage and loaded dynamically at run time via **PreApplicationStartMethod**.  Here is how I'm loading these .DLLs:

```
var corePluginAssemblyFiles = CorePluginsFolder.GetFiles("*.dll", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

foreach (var assemblyFile in corePluginAssemblyFiles)
{
    var assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(assemblyFile.FullName);
    System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.AddReferencedAssembly(assembly);
}
```

Now, among these plugins, I'm actually able to reference back and forth any which way I want and everything works fine.  But, when trying to use one from my login page **LoginController** (*which is in the /bin folder and not the /CorePlugins folder*) it says that it cannot find the .Dll in question:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Core.API.UserMgmt, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The network path was not found.
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Core.API.UserMgmt, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The network path was not found.
>
> Source File: C:\svn\HomeCenter_DEV\HomeCenter\HomeCenter.Core\Controllers\LoginController.cs    Line: 202
>
> Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'Core.API.UserMgmt, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' could not be loaded.
>
> === Pre-bind state information ===
>
> LOG: DisplayName = Core.API.UserMgmt, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
>    (Fully-specified)
>
> LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/svn/HomeCenter_DEV/HomeCenter/HomeCenter.Core/
>
> LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
>
> Calling assembly: HomeCenter.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.
>
> ===
>
> LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
>
> LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\svn\HomeCenter_DEV\HomeCenter\HomeCenter.Core\web.config
>
> LOG: Using host configuration file: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet.config
>
> LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
>
> LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
>
> LOG: The same bind was seen before, and was failed with hr = 0x80070035.

So just for giggles I placed a copy of the .DLL in the /bin folder as well, and low and behold it said it can't load the assembly because its already loaded.  So now I'm thinking what the hell.  So using some test code I printed out the loaded assemblies from **System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies()** and from **AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()** and I do in fact see the .DLL I'm trying to use `Core.API.UserMgmt, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null`.  So whats going on here?  Why can't it find the DLL that has clearly already been loaded. If I place the .dll in the /bin folder and remove it out of the `/CorePlugins` folder, it works, but then everything else that I have set up breaks.  I need the .dll to be in the `/CorePlugins` folder.

Comment: It could be in the temporary asp.net files location?

Comment: I know where the file is, and I load it via AddReferencedAssembly(), but the problem is from the LoginController it says it can't find it  Even though I can see that the library is loaded when I check the loaded assemblies.

Answer (score 0):

I can't quite remember which post I found that lead me to solving this, but essentially adding a `probing` element to `assemblyBinding` section in my `Web.Config` is what solved this for me.

```xml
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <probing privatePath="folder\subFolder1;folder\subFolder2;folder\subFolder3" />
      <!--  Other stuff -->
</assemblyBinding>
```

I had to add the root folder of every DLL I wanted to include because I couldn't figure out how to get it to recursively traverse the directory.